# A good performance alternative to PHP - String/File Manipulation

Tags: php, c++

I have a project that is done but needs better performance.

The gist of the project is that I'm taking XML and converting it to CSV files. The files represent data to be loaded into a Database.

Right now I'm using PHP to unzip the zip file that contains the XML. Then I parse, convert to CSV, and rezip.

It's been fine till now but the XML files are getting HUGE now. So much that processing takes a little more than a day. I'm also doing some manipulations in there somewhere to the files, like rearranging columns and trims.

What alternatives do you suggest that would help me improve performance?

I've thought about writing this parser in C++ but I'm not sure of what route to take. Similar questions have been asked but this is more of a performance issue I suppose. Should I switch languages for performance, stick with PHP and optimize that, should I try to make this parser parallel so more than one file can be done at a time?

What would you suggest?

Comment: "gist" is a word? :O And I thought github was just being fancy...

Comment: What are you using to parse the XML files? XML_Parser, XMLReader, SimpleXML, DOMDocument?

Comment: PHP is not exactly the fastest language around, but how "huge" are the XMLs? And how are you importing them? Using buffers or reading the whole thing into memory? It would help if you show us some code.

Comment: i agree with Alix.  please elaborate on "HUGE" nothing should take you all day, this isnt the 70's anymore

Comment: I agree with the others; it is far more likely that your problem is in your implementation, not inherent to the language.  It's easy to blame the language, but I can make any language parse a large XML file slowly.  For example, if you're loading the whole things into memory and parsing the entire thing for each tag you're looking for that will always be slow.  You need a forward looking, stream oriented parser.

Comment: So they aren't really xmls. They have an xml header but that's about it. I haven't used one of the XML parsers you mentioned for this reason. Aside from the XML opening tag the whole file is really a pseudo CSV with a weird character being used as a delimiter. 

Each file represents a table, and each table can easily have 10 million records/lines....everyday. And there are 70 tables.

Comment: You guys are right. I should look at the current code because I think that it's not well coded. There are many pieces of it that I didn't do. I'll come back when I have a better question to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give Perl a try if PHP doesn't deliver what you wont, but I doubt, maybe you are doing something wrong there (logically).

What kind of XML parser are you using? (Its better be a SAX one...).

Also, it would be nice to see some code (how you parse the XMLs...)

Comment: I'm going to revisit the code and look at how it's all coded.